# Adding Custom icon to HTML Page

Tags: html

I found this way to add default icons to any HTML page using i element :
[W3.CSS Icons](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_icons.asp)

Can I use the same way to have custom icon with the same way by adding my image?

adding markup after changes :

```
                      <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="#"><span class="icon"></span><span>Main Itmes</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/Page1.aspx">Item1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/Page2.aspx">Item2</a>
                        </li>
                                                    <li>
                            <a href="/Pagee3.aspx">Item3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

CSS :

```
        <style>
            .icon {
        background: url("Images/logo.png");
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        display: block;
        /* Other styles here */
    }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sure, although it depends on how you want to handle it.

**Regarding Icon Fonts**

Most of the images used in your examples are actually based on fonts that was create map each glyph to a specific Unicode value and then use CSS classes to set the `content` property to that specific value, thus displaying the icon. It's unlikely that you would want to make a font to do just that, but there are quite a few out there that you might want to explore if you want to use a uniform set of icons for your site or application.

**Using CSS Classes**

A simpler approach would be to create a CSS class that points to your specific image as a background and sets the amount of space necessary to accommodate it :

```
.icon {
    background: url('your-image-url.jpg');
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: block;
    /* Other styles here */
}
```

You would then need to just create an element that has that CSS class to display your icon :

```
<span class='icon'></span>
```

**Example**

```css
.icon {
  background: url('http://s.mobileread.com/i/icons/icon7.gif');
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  display: block;
  /* Other styles here */
}
```

```html
<i class='icon'></i>
```

Comment: So I shoul use span instead of I element ?

Comment: It's a matter of preference, some people prefer `<i>` tags but it's up to you, for this purpose there won't be much of a difference between the two (`<div>`, `<b>`, and others will work just as expected as well).

Comment: You need to make sure that your path is correct. Sometimes it's safer to use an absolute path of possible as any relative paths will be relative to where the CSS declaration is at.

Comment: I tried different URLs and online URLs  but still the same. These URL appears regularly with <img> tag

Comment: Could you post what your current markup and CSS looks like?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, this is likely an issue of your URL being relative. Since you are declaring it inline within a `<style>` block, you might consider resolving the absolute URL using the `ResolveUrl()` method as seen here : `background: url('<%= ResolveUrl("~/Images/logo.png") %>');`

Comment: I tried this waybut the same result. Icon doesn't appear

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what could be going wrong. What does your rendered markup look like (i.e. after the page is rendered, what does the `<style>` block look like)? Do you have any errors present within the Developer Tools (F12) in your browser?

Comment: No errors. style after rendering : 
        .icon {
    background: url('/Images/logo.png');
                
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: block;
    /* Other styles here */
}

Comment: I'm not sure what is going wrong. The code should be resolving the proper location for your image and serving it as expected. I added a demo that targeted an external URL and it is working just fine.

Comment: I tried your external image and still the same result

Comment: thanks Rion for your effort and interest , the problem was that image is Png when i use nay other JPG it works properly. only I had problem that this item is in new line :</span><span>Main Itmes</span>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add the custom icon to span or i.

1. Give your span a class name.
2. Set your icon as a background-image. Set background-size.
3. If it doesn't work, add style to span and set width and height the same as you set to background-size.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
 width:700px;
 height:700px;
 margin-top:50px;
}
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  float:left;
}

.title {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 18px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: black;
}

button:hover, a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.card1{
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-left:6px;
  
  text-align: center;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- Add icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="card">
  <img src="g.jpg" alt="John" style="width:50%">
  <h1>Bilal</h1>
  <p class="title">CEO & Founder, Example</p>
  <p>Stacker </p>
  <p>
  <a href="#"><img title="facebook" alt="facebook" src="fb.png" width="30px"></a> 
  <a href="#"><img title="facebook" alt="facebook" src="t.png " width="30px></a> 
  <a href="#"><img title="facebook" alt="facebook" src="i.png " width="30px ></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> 
  </p>
  <p><button>Contact</button></p>
</div>
<div class="card1">
  <img src="g.jpg" alt="John" style="width:50%">
  <h1>Bilal</h1>
  <p class="title">CEO & Founder, Example</p>
  <p>Stacker </p>
  <p>
  <a href="#"><img title="facebook" alt="facebook" src="fb.png" width="30px"></a> 
  <a href="#"><img title="facebook" alt="facebook" src="t.png " width="30px></a> 
  <a href="#"><img title="facebook" alt="facebook" src="i.png " width="30px ></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> 
  </p>
  <p><button>Contact</button></p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```