# Sass extend / CSS overwrite some properties

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to create a small custom icon libary to use with my website following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307278/adding-custom-icon-to-html-page/50315229):

It works for single icon but I don't want to write it for every icon i am going to use.
So I tried to use SASS / SCSS to do something easier:

```
 .icon {
    height: 4.5rem;
    width: 4.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.google-icon {
    background: url('../icons/icon.png');
    @extend icon;
}
```

and it generate this CSS:

```
.icon, .google-icon {
  height: 4.5rem;
  width: 4.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.google-icon {
  background: url("../icons/icon.png");
}
```

And it doesn't work, the background-size and background-repeat values are being overwriten, i don't know by what, but they don't apply, I can see the i element i've been using to insert the icon, and in thd dev tools i can see the image that I used but because this 2 properties being overwritten it doesn't show properly.
If I use @Mixin it works fine but from what I heard it's better to use @extend when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Few issues in your snippet:

```
.google-icon {
    background: url('../icons/icon.png');
    @extend icon;
}
```

- Your extend should be `@extend .icon`, see the "**.**" ?
- You are using `background: url('../icons/icon.png')`, when you should use `background-image: url('../icons/icon.png')`.

`background` is a ***shorthand***, it means that it's a way to provide a value for multiple properties. (*e.g.: background-image, background-size, background-position, background-color, etc...*). That line is overwritting your former rules.

To avoid the use of `@extend` you could follow a different methods:

#### CSS [attribute^=value] Selector

```
[class^=icon-] {
    height: 4.5rem;
    width: 4.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.icon-google { // The classname will start with icon-
    background-image: url('../icons/icon.png'); // background-image instead of background
}
```

By using `[class^=icon-]`, every html element with a class starting with `icon-` will be selected.
This way, if all your icons classname are starting with `icon-`, like `icon-google`, you won't need any extend.